# For which values of K is x in the span of u and v solve for unknown variable.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have  $u=\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\0\end{pmatrix}$

$v=  \begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$

I need to find what value(s) of *k* is $x= \begin{pmatrix}k\\4\\1\end{pmatrix}$ is in the span of *u* and *v*

I have set up an augmented matrix here:
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & k \\
2 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$
and I first start to reduce here. R1 = R1-2R3\
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & k-2 \\
2 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

Then I thought to swap R2 and R3 like so:
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & k-2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

I then see that R3 is a multiple of 2 and can reduce that like so:
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & k-2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

This is where I get stuck, I think I am almost there but I can't seem to get the rest.

Comment: From $R_1$ and $R_3$ we deduce that $k-2=2$ , hence $k=4$

Comment: The span of $u$ and $v$ is just the plane $2x-y-4z=0$. Replacing $(x,y,z)=(k,4,1)$ yields $2k-8=0$ which is saying $k=4$.

Answer (score 1):

You issue is equivalent to the fact that

$$\det(u,v,x)=0 \iff \begin{vmatrix}1&2&k\\2&0&4\\0&1&1\end{vmatrix}=0,$$

then expand the determinant (Sarrus expansion), which will give you

$$2k-8=0 \ \ \implies \ \ k=4$$